# How to get string value in power bi with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I want to get the text value from latest month but I don't know what's wrong with the DAX.

```
cm_comm =
VAR MaxKey = [MaxMonthKey]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        VALUES ( atm_commentary[Commentary] ),
        atm_commentary[MonthRolNo] = MaxKey
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Depends on your data, please show us a table with a sample of your data, showing all of the relevant columns (Especially every column in your DAX query), ideally as formatted text in your question,

Comment: Hi Jeff,i attached the table in the question.

Comment: Where do MaxKey and MaxMonthKey come from?

Comment: MaxKey is just the variance set for MaxMonthKey, it's just for this formula. MaxMonthKey is the measure I made for another table to find the latest month which is 4. so that my current formula will know it needs to look for row 4 and get this row's commentary.